# In python selenium get_attribute('value') does not return None when attribute does not exist in web element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, attributes, return, nonetype

I have a textbox in a form and I want to know if its blank.
get_attribute() should return None if the attribute does not exist, but it's returning nothing, blank, empty space.
I want to check that the attribute value does not exist in the web element below.
Here's the web element:

```
<input type="text" name="newPhone2" size="12" maxlength="10">
```

and I want to return 'None' since 'value' attribute does not exist.

```
new_phone2 = self.driver.find_element(By.NAME, "newPhone2")
if new_phone2.get_attribute('value') == None:
 # Do blah blah blah
```

Even though value is not an attribute in the web element, get_attribute() does not return None. It returns nothing...
For example:

```
print(new_phone2.get_attribute('value'))
```

The element is found but prints blank space instead of None. I expected it to print None, so I can use None as my if condition. I even tried empty quotes as my condition, but that does not work.

Why is it blank and not returning None? If the value was there, it returns the value, but not returning None when value doesn't exist.

if web element have a value, it will return the value.
For example,

```
<input type="text" name="newPhone2" value="123456' size="12" maxlength="10">
```

```
print(new_phone2.get_attribute('value'))
```

This will print 123456. But if value attribute was not there, it does not return None.

Comment: I'm guessing that `<input>` elements always have a `value` attribute, even if it's not explicitly given in the html.  That's the point of `<input>` elements, right?  They let the user input some **value**.  If the user hasn't entered anything, it will be a blank string.

Comment: but wouldn't my if condition be true if I did: 
if new_phone2.get_attribute('value') == " ":
This still doesn't work.

Comment: That looks like you're comparing it against a string that actually has one space in it.  But it would be an empty string, it would not have a space.  i.e. you want `""`, not `" "`.

Comment: The quotes with no space worked, thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the return type of `get_attribute` it says `str` so `if new_phone2.get_attribute('value') == None:` will never be evaluated to true no matter what.

When an element does not have an attribute that you are searching for it will return a `""` which can be evaluated as a falsy value.

Your updated code should be

```py
new_phone2 = self.driver.find_element(By.NAME, "newPhone2")
if not new_phone2.get_attribute('value'):
 # Do blah blah blah
```

Now if you want to consider white spaces to be a false too then you can use this instead

```py
if not new_phone2.get_attribute('value').strip():
```